# Securing Rest Web Service for Public Authentication - Server to Server

Tags: java, rest

I've a have a public RESTful API that is used for user authentication for a web application that accepts the user id and password in clear text (see below).  The username is passed in the url path as a path parameter and the password is a query string parameter.  The HTTP GET comes from another web application on the server side (http client request), is this API secure?  I was under the impression that the URL can not be seen if the request is going from server to server. My main fear is that someone could use something like firebug and see the traffic and get the userid and password.

**REST end point:**

```
HTTP GET https://host:80/user/joebob?password=pass123
```

Comment: I think it can be seen, just not by someone on the user's end. Why don't you just do a post to be safe?

Comment: @Hassan - I was worried about the URL being seen with the user id/pwd in clear text in something like firebug or another applicable sniffer.  The service consumer is doing a HTTP POST to the REST web service using HTTPClient.  Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone most definitely could see the username and password with a simple network sniffer.  If you are POSTing the request, why are the parameters in the URL?  They should be in the body like a normal POST, then at least the SSL protection kicks in and people can't sniff them.  Another option would be for you to look at HTTP Basic Auth.

Comment: I misspoke...its doing a http GET.  If I change the service to accept a POST and put the params in the body and not the URL and its under SSL then it can't be sniffed?

Comment: If you change to POST and put the params in the body and send over SSL then they won't be able to sniff the data in the body.

Comment: thanks for the help...what if the POST request was initiated from a client side framework like jquery?

Comment: POST is POST regardless of whether it's from a "real" browser, jQuery, httpunit, etc.  As long as it puts the parameters in the body instead of as query parameters you should be fine.